# How to assign text value to control for bool model

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

This may be a simple syntax issue, but I have a (bool) model and I want to assign the value attribute to custom text based on the state of the model. Following is my code where I have been stuck for a while now:

```
<input type="button" id="btnLikeContent" name="btnLikeContent" value=@{(Model.IsUserLikesContent) ? "Unlike" : "Like"} />
```

The intellisense error I get is "**The attribute requires a value, if the value is enclosed in quotation marks, the quotation marks must match**"

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
<input type="button" id="btnLikeContent" name="btnLikeContent" value='@(Model.IsUserLikesContent ? "Unlike" : "Like")' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your value in quote:

```
value='@{(Model.IsUserLikesContent) ? "Unlike" : "Like"}'
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried that before, the error I got is "Only assignment,call, increment, decrement, await and new object expressions can be used as statements"... the engine seems to think that it's a statement